# Proposition 4.4.5 in The Large Scale Structure of Space-Time

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, vector-fields, geodesics

In the text by Hawking and Ellis they set the following proposition (pg. 101):

> Proposition 4.4.5
>
> If $R_{ab} K^a K^b \geq 0$ everywhere and if at $p = \gamma(v_1)$, $K^c K^d 
>   K_{[a}R_{b]cd[e}K_{f]}$ is non-zero, there will be $v_0$ and $v_2$ such that $q = 
>   \gamma(v_0)$ and $r = \gamma(v_2)$ will be conjugate along $\gamma(v)$ provided $\gamma(v)$
> can be extended to these values.

So my question is: why does the term $K^c K^d K_{[a}R_{b]cd[e}K_{f]}$ have this form?

The authors say: If $K^c K^d K_{[a}R_{b]cd[e}K_{f]}$ is non zero then so is $R_{m4n4}$, but there is no additional explanation.